# Compiler Error Message: CS1502 when changing from ddl to txt

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
        //if (ddlALNR.Items.Contains(new ListItem(ProductDetailEntity.orderEccDetls.Alnr)))
        if (txtALNR.Text.Contains(new ListItem(ProductDetailEntity.orderEccDetls.Alnr)))
```

Hi, I am trying to change from dropdownlist to textbox in the code. Any idea what is the problem when the compiler output shows the message.

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'string.Contains(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: The error says it: it expects a `string`. `new ListItem(ProductDetailEntity.orderEccDetls.Alnr` is not a string, its a `ListItem`

Comment: you should check `if (txtALNR.Text.Contains(ProductDetailEntity.orderEccDetls.Alnr))`

Comment: `string.Contains(string)` certainly requires string as passed argument. If `ProductDetailEntity.orderEccDetls.Alnr` is a string property, use it instead of `ListItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (txtALNR.Text.Contains(ProductDetailEntity.orderEccDetls.Alnr))
```

Textbox - holds only one value,
Dropdown - holds multiple values